# Weird in a regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I tried the following regular expression:

Pattern: ((.[^[0-9])+)(([0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{3})+)|([0-9]+))

My goal is to match any string (excluding digit number) followed by a specified number, e.g. MG2999, dasdassa33232

I used the above regular expression.

It's weird as follows:

V375 (not matched)

Vv375 (matched)

Vvv375 (not matched, but first character is not matched)

Vvvv375 (matched)

...

I don't understand why the first character is never matched. May I need your help?

For your quick test, please try: http://regex101.com/

Thanks in advance!

--
Vu

Comment: "Match alphabetic string followed by a number": `[a-zA-Z]+\d+`

Comment: Yours does not include Unicode characters. Also my number is a bit different. Is my pattern wrong?

Comment: You asked for *alphabetic* characters. Unicode characters are not necessarily alphabetic. Your pattern takes into account number with decimals, but none of your example shows it is needed, so I got rid of that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.[^[0-9])+)` matches *any character* (`.`), followed by *any character except digits and `[`*, repeatedly.

You probably want `[^0-9]+` here – or, simpler, `\D+`.

The rest of there regular expression has similar problems but since I don’t know the number format you want to match I cannot correct that.

Comment: Yeh, I recognized my mistake. Actually, (([^0-9])+)(([0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{3})+)|([0-9]+)) works correctly with Boost.regex. Thanks!